# HashMap<String, Object> : How to put Object itself as in place of String

Tags: java, hashmap

```
A a = new A();     //classA {   }

HashMap<String, Object> hm = new Hashmap<String,Object>();

hm.put("A", a);
```

My question is, How can i put the Object itself instead of "A" in same declaration?

```
hm.put(`a??`, a);
```

Comment: It makes little sense to have a hashmap's key be the same as its value.

Comment: You *can* write `hm.put(a, a);` if you declare your map with the proper generic types.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, why do you want to do that?

Comment: @platzhirsch: just wanted to know if we can do somehow. just an interview question in which i got confused.

Comment: @user1010399: Your question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @user1010399 Okay, I have added some information to that in my question. My guess is, the interviewer wanted to see whether you understood the Generic Type Parameters in Java.

Comment: It could be done using `hm.put(a.toString(), a)`, but remember that every object you will add in your map must override the `toString` (or it will use the ugly `Object#toString`) method and you should store every String in some place. IMHO, this is silly and it shouldn't be used in real code.

Comment: @platzhirsch: you are absolutely right and his very next question was about `generic`. may be he wanted to judge something else ;(

Answer (score 3):

You simply cannot do that, the language prohibits it. It would only be possible if your class `A` is a subclass of `String` which is not possible, since `String` is declared as `final` in Java.

With respect to you interview question: It's not possible due to the generic type parameter that was chosen for the declaration. You can read more about that in [Bounded Type Parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html).

Comment: i totally agree with you but interviewer told me it can be done but you have to use some (dirty)tricks while he didn't tell me about that.

Answer (score 1):

```
A a = new A();     //classA {   }

Map<A, A> hm = new Hashmap<A, A>();

hm.put(a, a);
```

But I do not see any point of putting `a->a`

Answer (score 0):

If the class held a non-changing decent String field, you could use that.

```
// the id property must be a String, immutable and unique for each instance!
myMap.put(a.getId(), a);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make any **`object`** as a key in your **`HashMap`**, then that object has to be **`immutable`**.. Because, you don't want anyone to **change your key**, after you add them to your `HashMap`..

Just imagine, if your keys are changed after insertion, you won't ever be able to find your inserted value..

But if your key is `immutable`, then if anyone tries to change your keys, he will actually create a new one for himself, but you will still have yours..

That is what happens in case you use `String` as your key in `HashMap`(They can't be changed).. So, if you want your object to be a key, either you make your class a subclass of String (that you can't do), or, just make your class immutable..

Answer (score 0):

This is actually possible using a [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html), like this:

```
Object key = ...;
Object value = ...;
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();//a normal map
Map rawMap = map; // here is the raw type
rawMap.put(key, value); // it works!
```

This runs fine, but problems arise when you try to use the generic map later:

```
Integer value = map.get(key);// ClassCastException (unless value actually is an Integer)
```

That's why you were told that it's a "dirty trick". [You shouldn't use it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)